# Implementing an algorithm with dictionaries

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have to implement the following algorithm: [equation](http://www.innovagen.se/custom-peptide-synthesis/peptide-property-calculator/netcharge.gif) where "i" contains R, K, H and the Nterm and "j" contains D, E, C, Y, and the Cterm positive which returns a net charge. That method is used by another method to calculate the pI which is basically the pH value that gives the lowest charge.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class ProteinParam :


    aa2mw = {
        'A': 89.093,  'G': 75.067,  'M': 149.211, 'S': 105.093, 'C': 121.158,
        'H': 155.155, 'N': 132.118, 'T': 119.119, 'D': 133.103, 'I': 131.173,
        'P': 115.131, 'V': 117.146, 'E': 147.129, 'K': 146.188, 'Q': 146.145,
        'W': 204.225,  'F': 165.189, 'L': 131.173, 'R': 174.201, 'Y': 181.189
        }
    mwH2O = 18.015
    aa2abs280= {'Y':1490, 'W': 5500, 'C': 125}
    aacomp = {}
    aa2chargePos = {'K': 10.5, 'R':12.4, 'H':6}
    aa2chargeNeg = {'D': 3.86, 'E': 4.25, 'C': 8.33, 'Y': 10}
    aaNterm = 9.69
    aaCterm = 2.34


    def __init__ (self, protein):
        l = ''.join(protein).split()
        l = ''.join(l).upper()
        clean_prot = ""
        for aa in l:
            if aa in ProteinParam.aa2mw:
                clean_prot += aa
            else:
                pass
        self.protString = clean_prot
        for i in ProteinParam.aa2mw:
            ProteinParam.aacomp[i] = 0
        for aa in self.protString:
            if aa in ProteinParam.aacomp:
                ProteinParam.aacomp[aa] += 1

    def aaCount (self):
        return(len(self.protString))

    def pI (self):
        best_charge = 100000000
        for test_pH in range (14000):
            test_pH += 1
            test_pH = (test_pH / 100)
            new_charge = self.charge(test_pH)
            if new_charge < best_charge:
                best_charge = new_charge
        return best_charge

    def aaComposition (self) :
        return ProteinParam.aacomp

    def charge (self, pH):
        self.pH = pH
        negative = 0
        positive = 0
        for pos in ['R', 'K', 'H']:
            positive += ((ProteinParam.aacomp[pos]) * ((10 ** ProteinParam.aa2chargePos[pos]) / (((10 ** ProteinParam.aa2chargePos[pos])) + (10 ** self.pH))))
        positive += ProteinParam.aaNterm
        for neg in ['D', 'E', 'C', 'Y']:
            negative += ((ProteinParam.aacomp[neg]) * ((10 ** self.pH) / (((10 ** ProteinParam.aa2chargeNeg[neg])) + (10 ** self.pH))))
        negative += ProteinParam.aaCterm
        total = positive - negative
        return total    

prot_in = input("Enter a protein: ")
prot_obj = ProteinParam(prot_in)
x = prot_obj.pI()
print(x)
```

The problem is that I keep getting back 6.35 when I call pI() no matter what I input, I can't figure out what the problem is. I suspect it is in the charge() method by I can't tell where and the lack of errors doesn't narrow it down. The input 'VLSPADKTNVKAAW' should give a pI of 9.88. Any ideas?

Comment: We don't have a login for your school. Well, most of us.

Comment: You have a [logic error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error) and need to debug accordingly. Study the flow of your program and print/log some variables/checkpoints.

Comment: "The problem is that I keep getting back 6.35 when I call pI() no matter what I input " : that is false, try K or DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PROGRAMMING PROBLEM

If you are using Python2 then be careful with the line:

```
test_pH = (test_pH / 100)
```

because this will divide and round down to the nearest integer.

It may help if you use:

```
test_pH = (test_pH / 100.)
```

### LOGIC PROBLEMS

There are also 3 logical problems:

1. You need to return the best pH found, not the best charge found
2. You need to search for the pH where the charge is closest to zero, not where it reaches its most negative value
3. You need to use the formula to adjust the values for the terminii, not simply add on the raw values

In other words, instead of :

```
positive += ProteinParam.aaNterm
```

you need

```
positive +=  (10.**ProteinParam.aaNterm / (10. ** ProteinParam.aaNterm + 10. ** self.pH))
```